# Joining two DataFrames with Different Sizes and filling the empty values with null

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two one-column dataframes. One of which is 297 rows in length (I'll call this df1) and the other is 59 rows in length (I'll call this df2). I want to merge them together so that df2 matches with the bottom 59 rows of df1. The remaining 238 rows in the newly added df2 will be filled with NaN. How should I do this?

[image: This is a visual representation of what I want to achieve]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `df1` is at least as long as `df2`, set the index of `df2` with the end of that of `df1` and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = pd.concat([df1, df2.set_axis(df1.index[-len(df2):])], axis=1)
```

example input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('ABCDEFGH')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col2': list('WXYZ')})
```

output:

```
  col1 col2
0    A  NaN
1    B  NaN
2    C  NaN
3    D  NaN
4    E    W
5    F    X
6    G    Y
7    H    Z
```

intermediate `df2` with part of `df1`'s index:

```
df2.set_axis(df1.index[-len(df2):])

  col2
4    W
5    X
6    Y
7    Z
```

###### generalization

you can generalize to align to other parts, for example to align to the bottom minus 1 row:

```
skip = 1
pd.concat([df1, df2.set_axis(df1.index[-len(df2)-skip:-skip])], axis=1)
```

output:

```
  col1 col2
0    A  NaN
1    B  NaN
2    C  NaN
3    D    W
4    E    X
5    F    Y
6    G    Z
7    H  NaN
```

Comment: @HieuVuong carefully check my example. They aren't the same length, my only prerequisite is that `df1` is longer (or equal) to `df2`. Please provide your own example if needed.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly. If possible could you please explain a little about what's actually happening when you do df2.set_axis(...)

Comment: This sets df2's axis to be the end of that of df1 for alignment with `concat`. try to compare the index of `df2` and `df2.set_axis(df1.index[-len(df2):])`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple trick. reverse both dataframes, concatenate them and reverse them back. For reversing you can use `df.iloc[::-1]` or `df.reindex(index=df.index[::-1])`

You will need to reset index as well. You can use

```
df = df.reindex(index=df.index[::-1]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: That wouldn't work as `concat` is aligning the indices, and `reindex` is filling non-matches with NaN

Comment: You need to reset index. I have done this using `df1 = df1.reindex(index=df1.index[::-1]).reset_index(drop=True)`. You will to perform it on df2 and concat_df as well

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have this data in order to simulate the shape of your DataFrames:

```
df_one = pd.DataFrame(data=np.linspace(1, 297, 297), columns=["one"])
df_two = pd.DataFrame(data=np.linspace(101, 159, 59), columns=["two"])
```

You can create an empty DataFrame with a shape of `df_one.shape[0]` minus `df_two.shape[0]`:

```
data_nan = [np.nan for _ in range(df_one.shape[0] - df_two.shape[0])]
df_nan = pd.DataFrame(data=data_nan, columns=["two"])
```

Then create a temporary Dataframe with `pd.concat`:

```
# df_nan in first place so non NaN values will be in the bottom part
# .reset_index(drop=True) to keep indexes consistency
df_tmp = pd.concat([df_nan, df_two]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

And in the end...

```
# axis = 1 because you want to "append" a new column, not rows
df = pd.concat([df_one, df_tmp], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
```